# Import Reports is not a choice by right clicking Reports folder in Solution Explorer

Tags: ms-access, reporting-services

Using Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server 2012 I created a new Report Server project.

The following 3 folders were created in the project:

```
Shared Data Sources
Shared DataSets
Reports
```

I tried to import an MS Access report by right clicking the Reports folder in the Solution Explorer. The only choices were:

```
Add New Report
Add >
```

The Add sub menu had only:

```
New Item
Existing Item
```

There was not any choice to choose:

```
Import Reports
```

How do I import the MS Access reports into the project? I was assuming it would have been there by choosing Existing Item but it was not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Books Online, [Importing Reports from Access (SSRS)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156375%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> You must have Access 2002 or a later version installed on the same
>   computer that Report Designer is installed on in order to use the
>   import feature. The data source for the Access reports must be
>   available when the reports are imported.

If you don't have this installed the option won't be available.